# exec() is not working

Tags: php, npm, exec

I am doing the conversion from youtube link to gif image ,but i faced some problem while executing exce() function.

```html
 echo  $ret = exec("youtube-to-gif -u https://www.youtube.com/watch?v={$vidID} -b $start_second -d $different_second -s 480x? -o {$filePath}{$fileName} -f 10", $out, $err);
```

I am using exec() ,but its not returning any value .Here i am not getting why it is not working.

Thanks ,any suggestion will highly appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

First, store your command in a variable and try echoing it and runnining in a terminal to see if it's valid at all:

```
$command = "youtube-to-gif -u https://www.youtube.com/watch?v={$vidID} -b $start_second -d $different_second -s 480x? -o {$filePath}{$fileName} -f 10";
echo $command . PHP_EOL;
echo  $ret = exec($command, $out, $err) . PHP_EOL;
```

If it works fine when you run it manually, try full path to youtube-to-gif. Assuming you are running php on Linux, you should be able to do it with this command:

```
which youtube-to-gif
```

Now replace `youtube-to-gif` with the full path in `$command`.